# Instantiate within Abstract class

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3

I have an abstract class which gives specific 'base' behavior to multiple sub classes.  I want to instantiate a Singleton inside this abstract class.  Is it good practice to:

a) instantiate a class within an abstract class
b) do this with a Singleton (I know these may be frowned upon)

For clarity I will give an example, the method instantiating the Singleton is:

```
public function createErrorRepository(repositoryType:String):void { 
    this._errorFactory = ErrorFactory.getInstance();
    this._errorRep = this._errorFactory.createErrorRepository(repositoryType);
}
```

I have abstract methods:

```
public function getTitle():String {
    throw new IllegalOperationError("Error - getTitle functionality not supported");
}
```

Maybe i'm over thinking, but would be good to get some confirmation this is good practice?

Thanks

Chris

N.B I am using as3 but have tagged Java as well due to similarity.

Comment: could you give a code example ? Generally there is nothing wrong with instantiating a class inside an abstract class.

Comment: ActionScript and Java are not really similar languages, apart from the common C-like syntax.

Comment: Thanks for your answers so far, I realise Java and as3 aren't similar but I believe a Java developer could give me an appropriate answer, apologies for the ambiguity!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it good practice to:
>   a) instantiate a class within an abstract class

It probably depends on the design, but there is nothing wrong with creating an instance of a class within an abstract class if the instance is something that all of the subclasses should have. In Java this is done with `protected` fields if the subclasses need to access the fields.

> b) do this with a Singleton

If the singleton is a heavy object (e.g. lots of fields, methods, and so on) which all the subclasses of the abstract class will need, then it's probably preferable to have only one instance shared among them. It looks like the ErrorRepository might well fit that description, as there doesn't seem to be a reason for multiple instances to exist.

One last thought: if you didn't write ErrorFactory, make sure that the `errorFactory.createErrorRepository(repositoryType)` method is returning the same instance in all cases. (Even if you did write it, it wouldn't be a bad idea to check. I speak from experience.)